# How to start React and Cypress together

Tags: reactjs, npm, cypress

I am trying to test a React.js app with Cypress, and I came across a problem.

I'm able to start my app which boots up in a few seconds:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view testapp in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3000/
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.123:3000/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

then run Cypress open and go through tests. Now the thing I would like to achieve is to run this setup headlessly in command line but I don't know how.

How to boot up the app and then start the cypress test and exit? I'm trying to follow the guides from their official site but still no success.

Comment: what are you doing to start your app? If it's from an npm script in package.json, you should be able to just add `cypress run` at the end of it. See: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line.html#Commands

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a script in package.json. 
Something like

```
"test": "node_modules\\.bin\\cypress run --spec 'path/to/test.js'"
```

After that, you can run

> npm run test

Answer (score 0):

For me [start-server-and-test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/start-server-and-test) did a great job

In package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "test": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:3000 cy:run",
      "cy:run": "cypress open"
  },
```

You run it with `yarn test` command